# Python logging class in Docker: logs gone

Tags: python, docker

For several years now I've used Python's logging class in the same way:

```
def get_module_logger(mod_name):
    """
    To use this, do logger = get_module_logger(__name__)
    """
    logger = logging.getLogger(mod_name)
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s [%(name)-12s] %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    return logger
```

Then in some module,

```
logger = get_module_logger(__name__)
```

Now, I am running a Python app that uses this inside of a Docker container. I am running the container with `-d -i -t`. When I am inside the container after a `docker exec -it containername /bin/bash`, I can see the logs if I execute a command in my python script that produces logs. However, from outside, `docker logs containername` never shows anything. I have tried running my container with `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0` per a few web posts and that did not help either. Tailing with `docker logs -f containername` never shows anything either. So all my logs, both stderr and stdout are empty. I have also tried `logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)` but to no avail.

What is wrong? Do I need to change something in the handler?

EDIT: my Dockerfile is very simple:

```
FROM python:3.5.1
MAINTAINER tommy@...
ADD . /tmp

#need pip > 8 to have internal pypi repo in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip 
#do the install
RUN pip install /tmp/py/

CMD myservice
```

EDIT2:

```
~ docker --version
Docker version 1.11.0, build 4dc5990
```

Comment: it is not logical to use `docker run -itd`, it is either `-it`or `-d`, not both

Comment: Can you show us the Dockerfile for your container?

Answer (score 9):

I was able to see the log outputs and was not able to reproduce your issue with your code.

I created a file called `tommy.py`:

```
import logging

def get_module_logger(mod_name):
    """
    To use this, do logger = get_module_logger(__name__)
    """
    logger = logging.getLogger(mod_name)
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s [%(name)-12s] %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    return logger

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_module_logger(__name__).info("HELLO WORLD!")
```

Ran the following:

```
docker run -d -v /tmp/tommy.py:/opt/tommy.py python:3.5 python /opt/tommy.py
```

And saw this:

```
$ docker logs -f sleepy_poincare 
2016-08-30 17:01:36,026 [__main__    ] INFO     HELLO WORLD!
```

Edit:
Here's my Docker version:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.12.0, build 8eab29e
```

Answer (score 4):

- PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0 is turn on buffered, the log will be all output when the docker is closed.

  1. https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUNBUFFERED

```
PYTHONUNBUFFERED
If this is set to a non-empty string it is equivalent to specifying the -u option.
```

2. https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u

```
-u
Force the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered. This option has no effect on the stdin stream.

See also PYTHONUNBUFFERED.

Changed in version 3.7: The text layer of the stdout and stderr streams now is unbuffered.
```

Answer (score -5):

This is an issue with docker, not python. With docker, the file system seen inside an instance is unique to that instance. Any changes made are not reflected on the host machine. This is a feature of the union file system that docker uses.

You can use "[data volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/)" to mount a directory on the host machine inside your docker instance. You can either copy your logs into the at directory, or (in the future) log directly to that directory.

On Unix:

```
docker run -v /Users/<path>:/<container path> ...
```

On Windows:

```
docker run -v /c/Users/<path>:/<container path> ...
```

This directory will exist outside of the union file system, so you lose the ability to shapshot the directory or roll back changes.

Comment: with my streamhandler set to () this just prints to stdout and stderr. It does not print to a file. I thought Docker logs with -t option was supposed to grab stderr and stdout.